# Unable to see measurements in influxdb

Tags: aws, influx-db

I am new to influxdb and I am having this trouble to show measurements.

Our setup is that prometheus(aws ec2) is writing data to Influxdb(aws ec2). When I execute 'SHOW MEASUREMENT' I cannot see anything. However, when I execute 'SHOW SERIES' I can see lot of time series.

Is there anyone who knows why I am seeing this? Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 2):

The command is `SHOW MEASUREMENTS`.  You left off the 'S' at the end.

Hope that helps!